# How do you dynamically store items in checkboxes in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am fetching a list of checkboxes from an API and displaying them respectively. What I want is to dynamically store the checkboxes in state and send the data to an API in the following format. Can anyone please help me with this? I haven't done this type of task before, and I am not able to store checkboxes dynamically using useState.

When i am trying to select one checkbox then every list of checkbox will selected for example if i select checkbox of add then every checkbox of add will selected and that not what i want.

```
{
  "name": "Role Name",
  "permissions": [
    {
      "name": ["Add", "Update", "View", "Delete"],
      "section": "section name"
    },
     {
      "name": ["Add", "Update", "View"],
      "section": "section name 1"
    }

  ]
}
```

**Check Box Component**

```
 const checkAll = plainOptions.length === props.checkedList.length;

  const checkAllGame = gameOptions.length === props.checkedList.length;

  const indeterminate =
    props.checkedList.length > 0 &&
    props.checkedList.length < plainOptions.length;

  const GameIndeterminate =
    props.checkedList.length > 0 &&
    props.checkedList.length < gameOptions.length;

  const onCheckAllChange = (event: CheckboxChangeEvent) => {
    props.setCheckedList(event.target.checked ? plainOptions : []);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="role-subject-title">
        <h3>{props.permissionTitle}</h3>
      </div>
      <div className="checkbox-design">
        <CheckboxGroup
          options={props.isGameOption ? gameOptions : plainOptions}
          value={props.checkedList}
          onChange={props.onChange}
          className="checkbox-style"
        />

        <Checkbox
          indeterminate={props.isGameOption ? GameIndeterminate : indeterminate}
          onChange={onCheckAllChange}
          checked={props.isGameOption ? checkAllGame : checkAll}
          className="checkbox-style-all"
        >
          <span style={{ color: "white", fontSize: "20px" }}>
            {APP_CHECKBOX_ROUTE.CHECK_ALL}
          </span>
        </Checkbox>
      </div>
    </>
  );
```

**Parent Component**

```
  const { permissionList, loading, error, addRole } = useSelector(
    (state: RootState) => state.roles
  );

  const defaultCheckedList = ["Add", "Update", "Delete", "View"];

  const [gameName, setGameName] = useState<string | undefined>(undefined);
  const [checkedList, setCheckedList] =
    useState<CheckboxValueType[]>(defaultCheckedList);

  console.log(permissionList, loading, error, addRole);

  const onChange = (list: CheckboxValueType[]) => {
    setCheckedList(list);
  };

  const getPermissionList = () => {
    dispatch(getPermission());
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getPermissionList();
  }, []);

 <Navbar>
      <div className="details-title">
        <h1>Roles </h1>
      </div>
      <div className="input-box-container">
        <InputField
          label=""
          name="gameName"
          onChangeText={event => setGameName(event)}
          placeholder="Role Name"
          errorMessage="Please input your password!"
          required
          value={gameName}
          type="text"
          styles={{
            width: 516,
            // padding: isMobileDevice ? "8px 6px" : "13px 10px",
            height: "60px",
            fontSize: 20,
            marginBottom: "0 !important",
            boxShadow: "0px 4px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)",
            borderRadius: 16,
          }}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="details-title">
        <h1>Permissions </h1>
      </div>
      <div style={{ marginTop: 33 }}>
        {permissionList.map((item, index) => (
          <Collapsible title={item.section} isFirst={index === 0} key={index}>
            <CheckBoxItem
              checkedList={checkedList}
              setCheckedList={setCheckedList}
              onChange={onChange}
              permissionTitle={""}
            />
          </Collapsible>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <Button htmlType="submit" className="login-button">
          Save
        </Button>
      </div>
    </Navbar>
```

Comment: Not super clear... Partial code. Now what looks obvious to me is you are NOT passing the `index` to `CheckBoxItem`... So the `setCheckedList` passed-in state setter will set a new state for.. I don't know what.

Comment: I have a list of checkboxes, for example:
***********
_________________
Section Name
__________________
[Add
Update
Delete
View]
*********
I want to dynamically store these items using useState. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Hew... Last comment is not helpful. --- You have to pass the `index` along with the passed-in state setter, so the checkbox can update the right index of an array in that parent state.

Comment: can you give me example? that can figure out my problem 

________________
{
  "name": "Role Name",
  "permissions": [
    {
      "name": ["Add", "Update", "View", "Delete"],
      "section": "section name"
    },
     {
      "name": ["Add", "Update", "View"],
      "section": "section name 1"
    }

  ]
}
______________

useState should look this this,

Comment: No. you have to understand the logic. -- You are giving a checkbox the tool to update a value. Which one? The checkbox does not know unless you tell it.

Comment: Thanks @LouysPatriceBessette, I think I did it, and let me check with the API